# Как правильно сформировать число с плавающей точкой из целого

Tags: php

На обработку приходят разные целые числа, например - `25, 154, 1548, 12525, 214589`
мне нужно преобразовать все эти числа таким образом: `0.025, 0.154, 1.548, 12.525, 214.589`, т.е. оставлять после точки тысячные.

Comment: А на 1000 не пробовали делить?

Comment: @Visman, действительно) что то я перегрелся сегодня, это же очевидно, делим на 1000 и всё работает. Благодарю! Я как всегда пытаюсь искать сложное решение, а оно проще простого.

Comment: я, товарищи, пожалуй добавлю этот вопрос к себе в избранное :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$input = [25, 154, 1548, 12525, 214589];

$output = array_map(function ($number) {
    return $number / 1000;
}, $input);

var_dump($output);
```